# Getting error while initializing structure variable?

Tags: c

I am confused about why I am getting an error while initializing a structure variable. I have found a few related threads on Stack Overflow, but they did not solve my problem. Can anyone explain what is causing the problem?

```
 //I have used Dev-C++ compiler
 //Getting an error 'b1' undeclared
  struct book
 {
           char name ;
            float price ;
            int pages ;
  };

   struct book b1;     

  int main()
 {

    /* First i have tried following way to initialize the structure variable,
    but compiler throws the error 

    b1 = {"John", 12.00, 18};

    */

     //I have tried to initialize individually ....but still getting error...?

     b1.name = "John";
     b1.price = 12.3;
     b1.pages = 23;

     printf ( "\n%s %f %d", b1.name, b1.price, b1.pages );


     system("pause");
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: ...you didn't even say what error you're getting. (But, if I had to guess, it would be that initializing a `char name` with a `char *` string doesn't work.)

Comment: use char name[100];strcpy(b1.name,"John");

Answer (score 0):

**Problems**

1. only one byte memory available for `name` field. use like `char name[100]`
2. use `strcpy()` instead of `b1.name = "John"`;

Answer (score 0):

You clearly want a string variable in your `struct`, but you declared it as `char name;` (a *single* character).

Instead, use a `char` pointer (`const char *name`), or a `char` array (`char name[100]`). In the latter case, you will have to use `strcpy(b1.name, "John")`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared `name` as a `char`. That means `name` will hold only a single `char`, not an entire string.

You can statically allocate `name` as an array of `char`:

```
char name [25]  // or whatever length you think is appropriate
                // remember to leave room for the NUL character
```

Then you will need to use `strcpy()` to copy the actual name into the structure.

Alternatively, you can declare `name` as a pointer to char:

```
char* name;
```

In this case, you can set the pointer to a string literal:

```
name = "John";
```

But in most real life situations, this is not an option, as you will be reading the name in from a file or standard input. So you will need to read it into a buffer, set the pointer to dynamically allocated memory on the heap (the string length of the buffer + 1 for the `NUL`), and then use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some tweaks to your code in order to make it work.

```
char name;  // only one byte is allocated.
```

Define char array to store strings in C.

```
char name[20]; //stores 20 characters
char *name; //Pointer variable. string size can vary at runtime.
```

Once you have created a object for your structure than you can feed data only using that object.

(i.e) object.element=something;

```
b1 = {"John", 12.00, 18}; // Not possible
```

The above initialization is possible only while defining objects.

```
struct book b1={"John", 12.00, 18}; //Possible
```

If  **char *name** is defined inside struct, you can do the following.

```
struct book b1;
b1.name="John";   // Possible
b1.price=12.00;   // Possible
b1.pages=18;      // Possible
```

If you use char array **char name[20]** then you can do the following.

```
struct book b1;
strcpy(b1.name,"John");  // Possible
b1.price=12.00;     // Possible
b1.pages=18;       // Possible
```

Comment: `b1.name = "John"` won't work if `name` is an array of characters.

Comment: @verbose Obviously it will not. We have to do strcpy for array. I have edited it.